# Buttons moving when border color changed

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have this page: http://new.unreal-designs.co.uk/quote/

If you click in a field and then out, it goes red as the validation on it has failed, but the buttons at the bottom seem to shift.

I am using the http://www.formvalidator.net/ plugin for the validation.

Can anyone tell me whats causing the buttons to move?

*Source removed as it was huge, can be seen at http://bit.do/bVpn9*

Answer (score 3):

When the form validates and throws an error a span error message in inserted in the DOM, by JS, after the button.

EG.

```
<span class="help-block form-error">You have not given a correct e-mail address</span>
```

Presumably this message changes length hence the jumping around.

[image]

You can't see it because there is a rule

```
body span {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

which is not changing, perhaps as it should.

Add a new rule

```
span.help-block.form-error {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
}
```

That will make the message visible and move it under the button

Comment: I added a rule to set display to none as I don't want the error message atm, but yeah, I get the idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is because the error span is appearing on the right side of the button. I guess that the whole div is centered and not just the button. This results in the button being shifted to the right.

At this moment the opacity is 0.

```
    body span {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

If you turn this into

```
    body span {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

You can clearly see why its shifted. If you intent to show the message, the solution would be to change the opacity. If you dont want to show the message at all and want to make sure the button does not shift to the left you should either stop the code from showing the error span or (if you don't know how to do that) add a

```
    style='display:none;'
```

to the span. This can be done inline as shown above or this can be done in the style.css file.

Comment: Same answer @Paulie_D gave. JS.

Answer (score 1):

You have a span class that shows up when there is an error filling out the code:

```
<span class="help-block form-error">You have not given a correct e-mail address</span>
```

Although you have the opacity set to 0, the text is still there.

```
body span {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

So you'd have to change whatever jQuery or plugin that controls the 'error' class and adds in the span text.

Although, if you want a temporary fix, add this to your css and it will stop the button from moving.

```
body span {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

This will remove the span text, but it's recommended you go into the plugin and edit it there.

Comment: Same answer @Paulie_D gave. JS.

Comment: It is not the same answer. Paulie's answer makes the text visible. This solution makes the text display to none.

Comment: Same logic though, that's all I'm saying. He found the issue, I can do basic CSS to fix it how I want. Not saying you did anything wrong, just pointing out 4 minutes after he posted, you then posted with the same answer as to the issue, which was what I asked for.

Also, your answer would hide all spans.... Not the error span on it's own.